# Error concrete type

Tags: go

I have a method `CreateProduct(&Product) error` that returns a value implementing `error` interface. It can be a `gorm` database error or my own error type.

Having the returned value, how can I know which type is the error?

```
err = api.ProductManager.CreateProduct(product)
if err != nil {
    // TODO: how to distinguish that it is a validation error?
    response.WriteHeader(422)
    response.WriteJson(err)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a **[type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)**, and act if the error returned is from the expected type:

```
if nerr, ok := err.(yourError); ok  {
  // do something
}
```

You can also do a **[type switch](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements)** for multiple test

```
switch t := err.(type) {
case yourError:
    // t is a yourError
case otherError :
    // err is an otherError
case nil:
    // err was nil
default:
    // t is some other type 
}
```

Note: a type assertion is possible even on `nil` (when `err == nil`):

> the result of the assertion is a pair of values with types `(T, bool)`.
>
> - If the assertion holds, the expression returns the pair `(x.(T), true)`;
> - otherwise, the expression returns `(Z, false)` where `Z` is the zero value for type `T`

Here, the "zero value" of "`Error`" would be `nil`.

Comment: How do I write the check nicely? Will `if err, ok := err.(yourError); ok  {` panic if `err == nil`?

Comment: @warvariuc no, and you can add a case for that: `case nil`

Comment: @warvariuc I have edited the answer to explain why you can do a type assertion on `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [type assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to do that:

```
if gormError, ok := err.(gorm.RecordNotFound); ok {
   // handle RecordNotFound error
}

if myError, ok := err.(MyError); ok {
   // handle MyError
}
```

When dealing with multiple error cases, it can be useful to use [type switches](http://golang.org/ref/spec#TypeSwitchStmt) for that:

```
switch actualError := err.(type) {
case gorm.RecordNotFound:
    // handle RecordNotFound
case MyError:
    // handle MyError
case nil:
    // no error
}
```

Comment: Just to add to the excelent answer, you can use `case nil`, that way you don't do an extra `if err != nil`.

Comment: @OneOfOne Thanks, I added the line to the type switch.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you would go about with any other interface. Use type assertion or a type switch:

```
switch err := err.(type) {
case MyValidationError:
    fmt.Printf("validation error")
case MyOtherTypeOfError:
    fmt.Printf("my other type of error")
default:
    fmt.Printf("error of type %T", err)
}
```

Go Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/5-OQ3hxmZ5